# featuresBoot not working in Fuse 7 (Karaf 4.2)

Tags: java, apache-camel, apache-karaf, jbossfuse, karaf

I'm migrating our code from Fuse 6 to to Fuse 7 (Developer editions).

We spin up lots of instances, so I need to automate the features loading like in Fuse 6, and it's not working.

I add the following to the /etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg

```
featuresBoot = \
    ...
    transaction-manager-narayana/5.7.2.Final, \ 
    camel-hl7/2.21.0.fuse-000077-redhat-1,\
    camel-mina2/2.21.0.fuse-000077-redhat-1,\
    camel-beanio/2.21.0.fuse-000077-redhat-1
```

and would expect it to install camel-hl7, camel-mina2 and camel-beanio.
But when I check in the client, it shows "Uninstalled".

They install if I do it manually with `feature:install`

What else do I need to do?  Help me Obi-wan.

Comment: I am now having this issue with fuse 6.3, and would LOVE to know how you resolved it...

Comment: Hi Hans, I ended up running a bash script to ping Fuse until it was up, and then call the client with 'features:install' commands. If you're still out of luck on Monday, I can post the script.

Comment: aha.  Thanks for your response.  I share similar sentiment to yours below--i.e., that _I_ may have made some odd/stupid mistake in this new installation.  However, I am lucky--I have a local environment wherein I have since confirmed that an older fuse-6.3 ansible playbook of mine, creates a working* fuse-6.3.  I am in the process of removing deltas between the 2 playbooks, and hope to nail this down to a single error somewhere in my newer playbook.  When I do, I will post what I find as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mystery solved.**  Ugh, indeed this is *stupid*--albeit, not on our part, I would argue.

The error is a trailing space, following the line continuation backslash on the line above the one where your 'missing' features are.  I found this in my `org.apache.karaf.features.cfg`, and verified it as the culprit.  I *also* see it in what is presumably a copy-paste of a snippet of yours.

```
    transaction-manager-narayana/5.7.2.Final, \ 
                                               ^
                                               |
                                               here
```

I feel like it is a major oversight in the Karaf code.  Presumably the config-admin service has some format rules--so that is probably the place to address it.  If it would at least log an error, that would be good.

Comment: Well done :)  That's a doozy.  Next time I fix up my code I'll redo that bit.

Answer (score 4):

`featuresBoot` property of Red Hat Fuse 7 (and Karaf 4 and even earlier) is used **only once** - when Karaf feature service starts for the first time. When `etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg` file is read and processed, feature service sets its `bootDone` flag to `true`.

If you want the feature to be processed after you run Fuse/Karaf and added new features later, you have to remove `data/cache` directory.

However it's usually not the way to do it. If you start Fuse/Karaf, you can simply install additional features you want - without adding to `etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg`. Just call `feature:install`.

If you need special Karaf distro with the features you want, please check a section of Karaf manual about [custom distributions](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/#_maven_assembly).

For Red Hat Fuse 7, there's special quickstart that shows how to do it - check `FUSE_HOME/quickstarts/custom`.

Comment: Thanks, my issue is that my additions to featuresBoot aren't being installed.  I'm adding with feature:install currently, to move forward, but I'll need to get featuresBoot working eventually, as we have 12 Fuses, so I need to automate it.  The custom Karaf is useful, thanks, I will read through it.  But ideally, featuresBoot should work as advertised. etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg has camel-hl7, but camel-hl7 doesn't show up in the logs, at all, and is "uninstalled" when I load the client.  Probably something obvious, but can't work it out yet.

Comment: If you could provide some steps to reproduce (like the version/archive you start with + commands you invoke / files you edit), I could maybe help.

Comment: Thanks for the offer.  Here's a simplified example: Download Fuse 7.0.0 (Karaf Installer, 175MB). Edit etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg.  Add camel-hl7/2.21.0.fuse-000077-redhat-1 to the end of the featuresBoot list, after transaction-manager-narayana. Save file.  Start fuse.bat... try 'list' or 'features:list' or check the logs.  No 'hl7', camel-hl7 still uninstalled.

Comment: Any idea?  featuresBoot doesn't work in Linux or Windows, for me.

Comment: works for me... is `etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg` the one you've shown before?

Comment: Yeah.  Pretty bizarre.  I literally just DL from the website, change that file, save, and start fuse, and the feature isn't installed.

Comment: Again, I checked your steps - I downloaded the distro from https://developers.redhat.com/products/fuse/download/, unzipped, didn't run `bin/fuse` yet, added 3 entries to `etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg`, started using `bin/fuse` and I saw both the bundles and features installed...

Comment: Ok thanks for trying.  I will start again from scratch. Maybe I did something stupid.